# Spring value injection of a Map of List of Maps

Tags: java, spring, data-structures, properties

This may sound crazy, but I am trying to get a properties file for my following data structure

```
@Value("#{${myBigMap}}")
Map<String, List<Map<String, String>>> myBigMap;
```

And the properties file should look like

```
myBigMap = { \
      "key1": [{subkey1:'subval1'}], \
      "key2": [{subkey3:'subval3'},{subkey4:'subval4'}] \
}
```

I can get the map of map to work, but this one seems too stretchy. I have  some System properties for other value injection. Not sure if I can manually combine yaml properties into the property sources.

It is not a Spring boot application. We just use Spring for dependency injection.

Would really appreciate any help/clue

Comment: not sure how to do this in spring but you can have this as a json string property, then inject the value in a string variable, and then using jackson convert it to whatever data structure you want

Comment: This is an ideal candidate for `@ConfigurationProperties` which is Spring Boot which you don't have. You could inject your property as a json string into a bean constructor String parameter then use the Jackson ObjectMapper to turn it into a map.

Answer (score 0):

thank you for hints. I actually got it working by using Jackson's yaml help

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory());
    try {
        Resource myResource = new ClassPathResource("my.yaml");
        Map<String, List<Map<String, String>>> myMap = mapper.readValue( myResource.getInputStream() , Map.class);
        }
```

and my yaml looks like

```
k1:
  - sk1: val1
  - sk2: val2

k2:
  - sk3: val3
  - sk4: val4
```